# Is there a way to set initial value for auto incremented column in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am using typeorm with postgresql. I want my auto incremented primary key column to start from specific initial value instead of 1. Is there any solution in typeorm for postgresql ?

Answer (score 1):

*TypeORM* does not support it, but *PostgreSQL* does support `SEQUENCE` (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)) which can be used to define a custom auto-increment column.

For example, define a `SEQUENCE` that starts at 50 and increments by 1 each time:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE
    increment_from_fifty
    start 50
    increment 1;
```

Then, use it to set the column you want to increment

```
INSERT INTO sample_table
    (id, title)
VALUES
    (nextval('increment_from_fifty'), 'Title 1');
```

Anything that can be done with *PostgreSQL* can be done with *TypeORM* because you can define custom queries using `EntityManager.query()` (see [docs](https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api)) or `QueryBuilder` (see [docs](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder)).